# jQuery : use $(this) inside object literal

Tags: jquery

Lets say we have this code:

```
$.fn.obList   = function(options){
  alert(options.o1);
}

$('li').obList({
  o1: $(this).attr('class')
});
```

I'm trying to access selected element(that is **li** ) inside options object given to function, 
but `$(this)` does not work and return *undefined*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
$('li').obList({
  o1: $(this)
});
```

The context of `this` is the `window`. So you need to use:

```
$('li').each(function () {
  $(this).obList({
    o1: $(this)
  });
});
```

You can also use:

```
$.fn.obList   = function(options) {
  alert($(this).attr("class"));  // This `this` here refers to the element.
};
```

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/qekonadomu**

```js
$.fn.obList   = function(options){
  alert(options.o1);
};

$('li').each(function () {
  $(this).obList({
    o1: $(this).attr("class")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li class="item-1"></li>
  <li class="item-2"></li>
  <li class="item-3"></li>
</ol>
```

For this, I get:

```
item-1
item-2
item-3
```

As the output.

Comment: Just as a side note, inside jquery prototype method, `this` is already refering to the jq matched set object and it hould always return it to keep chaining (unless used as a getter)

Comment: @A.Wolff Sure bro.. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create a scope where `this` is the element, and that could be done in many ways, a common way to do it is to use `each()`

```
$('li').each(function() {
    $(this).obList({
        o1: $(this).attr('class')
    });
});
```

Another would be to let the plugin handle it

```
$.fn.obList   = function(options){

    return this.each(function() {
        options = options || {};

        options.o1 = $(this).attr('class');
    });
}

$('li').obList();
```

Comment: Are you sure about **second** solution . I cant get it to work [jsfillde](https://jsfiddle.net/pishva/x54w1xk1/2/) . does `this` point to window or a single  element?

Comment: @alex - the each loop isn't to get the class, it's generally needed, and always a good practice, inside a jQuery plugin -> https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#using-the-each-method